# MySQL: Problems with hosts

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL server running on my Windows machine, and I wanted to add users capable of connecting from any host to it. In order to do so I used the statement

CREATE USER 'user_name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_pw'

but when I try to connect locally with this new user, it fails. Right now I solved the problem by calling CREATE USER twice, the first using '%' as host and the second using 'localhost', but I'd like to know if there's another solution or some option I have to change on the server

Comment: As you're new here, I remember you should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you think it solved (or helped to solve) your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html):

After connecting to the server as root, you can add new accounts. The following statements use GRANT to set up four new accounts:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost';
mysql> GRANT RELOAD,PROCESS ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
mysql> CREATE USER 'dummy'@'localhost';
```

Two of the accounts have a user name of **monty** and a password of **some_pass**. Both accounts are superuser accounts with full privileges to do anything. **The 'monty'@'localhost' account can be used only when connecting from the local host. The 'monty'@'%' account uses the '%' wildcard for the host part, so it can be used to connect from any host**.

**It is necessary to have both accounts for monty to be able to connect from anywhere as monty. Without the localhost account, the anonymous-user account for localhost that is created by mysql_install_db would take precedence when monty connects from the local host. As a result, monty would be treated as an anonymous user.** The reason for this is that the anonymous-user account has a more specific Host column value than the 'monty'@'%' account and thus comes earlier in the user table sort order. (user table sorting is discussed in Section 5.4.4, “Access Control, Stage 1: Connection Verification”.)

Comment: @Orgrim: I'm not sure of this. But I think you'd betteer to leave MySql behaving as standard, because this gives you the opportunity to check your logins better and to grant/revoke unwanted db accesses...